# Save and share an image created on website

Tags: php, jquery, css, facebook, share

I'm working on this fun tool on a website I'm working on that allows the user to drag images around (using jQuery UI) to create their own character.

You can see the basics of this working here: http://goo.gl/JVXM0

What I'm after, however, is the ability for the user to then share their creation via Facebook and Twitter. Whether once created, it takes a screenshot of an area then they can share their creation... I'm unsure.

Having a look at this, is there any steps or directions I can take to making this happen?

Any help would be so appreciated.

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: You'll likely need to do this server-side. Pass the coordinates of each item to a PHP script and have it use ImageMagick or GD to render it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to generate an image of the DOM on a page? If so, this would be a good question to start with:
[Generate image from DOM elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162678/generate-image-from-dom-elements)

Hope this helps!

Cheers, Robin