# Html dom elements to image (client side)

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to find a way to convert a part of a webpage in an image: I have a dynamically created page, and I would like to "save" a part of it, in an image format.

I know that turning html to image is quite complicated, and could be done by server-side computation with tools like phantom js or other webkit render engine. But I'm trying to find a way to achieve this in client side.

I imagine something like putting the dom elements in a svg (with foreignObject), then rendering the svg in a canvas, and then turning the canvas to base64 string url. But I tried, and I didn't manage to do it.

What do you think about this idea? does it sound possible? I think I first have a way to compute the dom elements css styles in an html string, but that seems very complicated. I guess I need some advice here.

Comment: Have you seen [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) yet?

Comment: In phase 2 "then rendering the svg in a canvas" exactly what HTML rendering engine would be involved?

Comment: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki

Comment: @ComFreek: No I've never seen that, it seems very interesting, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Daniel: I thought PhantomJS was only server-side. I'll read more the wiki to see if I can use it on client-side

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate image from DOM elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162678/generate-image-from-dom-elements)

Comment: you may want to try [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image)